# Oracle - Is it possible to maintain transaction across multiple schemas?

Tags: oracle, schema, transaction

I got this database in oracle which includes 4 schemas. Each schema represents a logical layer. Each transaction (Stored Procedure) in the upper layer breaks into a couple of transactions in the lower layer. So there is this scenario:

I execute a SP in the upper layer which results in some inserts in both layers but for some reason one of the transactions in the lower layer fails. Is it possible to rollback the whole thing?

Comment: Yes, this works fine. Just make sure there are no commits in any of your stored procedures, or at worst, only in the top-level stored procedures.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Actually this is not a good solution, because I might wanna call a procedure directly from the lowest layer. That procedure, which is an atomic logical operation, must be either committed or rolled back. One (imaginary) solution would be some chaining-like mechanism that you could bound the execution of some transactions to the execution of another. I'm not hopeful if such a feature exists!

Comment: Then, like I said, make sure there are NO commits in your stored procedures and do all the committing outside of them.

Comment: I added a "commit_op" parameter to all my SPs which let's the caller decide whether to commit it or not. @Colin'tHart, if you answered as an "Answer" I could accept yours :)

Comment: Why add parameter and if statement to each procedure when the caller could simply do `proc(); commit;` ?

Comment: Well, as I mentioned before, the SPs are logical atomic operations. Sometimes they are called by a parent proc as part of a bigger transaction, so they mustn't get committed. on the other hand there are cases that the SPs are called directly as one transaction, so they must commit themselves. The caller always knows whether the called SP should be committed or not.

Comment: There's no point in what are you trying to do because you can always control when the `commit;` is issued (the same way as you implement a parameter to control when it has to commit). And also, regardless of the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can, just be sure that the transactions are defined by the uppper layer - the client. A transaction has to be Atomic, so has to succeed (and commit) or has to fail (and rollback).

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle schema has nothing to do with transactions. Schema is a namespace and it is assocated with a user:

- it is the default namespace for this user if she issues an sql statement, e.g `select * from customers;` selects data from the table named customer of the current schema.
- she is the owner of the objects of this namespace which means she has some default privileges , e.g. select,insert,update,delete on her's tables.
- there are system privileges that applies for the default namespace, e.g. `create table` allows creation of the table in the schema (default namespace of the user)

There is no relation between schema and transactions.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: That's right. Transactions are schema namespace independient. I upvote.